# Footer does not appear correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, local.xml, footer

I have several `footer` and several `header` for different pages and I insert them through XML as follows in my local.xml:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate">
             <template>page/html/header_checkout.phtml</template>
        </action>
     </reference>
     <reference name="footer">
        <action method="setTemplate">
             <template>page/html/footer_checkout.phtml</template>
        </action>
     </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

The `header` is working perfectly, but the `footer` is not. For example, I load the home with a `footer` and I go to the page of the cart, even adding it by XML, it finishes that the `footer` of the home continues to appear in the cart. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the way in which I insert the phtml of the `footer` contained in the page from the following code through `XML`:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="page/html" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer_checkout.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Complete Code:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate">
             <template>page/html/header_checkout.phtml</template>
        </action>
     </reference>
     <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer_checkout.phtml" />
     </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the footer of the homepage for all pages, this is why you find it also in cart.

1. Try to find if you have some theme config in admin (Theme settings)
2. find in your **local.xml** inside `<default></default>` some footer setting and move it in the the correct layout handle instead of `<default>`
3. **app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml**

   ```
   <checkout_cart_index>
       <reference name="footer">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/footer_checkout.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
   </checkout_cart_index>
   ```
4. Clear the caches and it should work.

Comment: Even though I have already found the solution to this problem, I thank you for your help and attention in trying to help me by responding as well.